# How do I speed up the start time of my electron app?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

I'm developing an electron application and the thing I don't understand is **how apps like visual studio code achieve so fast startup times**, by that I mean the time between clicking the icon until a window opens (until main.js gets loaded).

I already read many articles about speeding up electron but they all just talk about the stuff that happens AFTER main.js is loaded.

I downloaded the electron-quick-start example and packaged it using electron-builder as portable app.

- Visual Studio Code: 1-2 secs until a window shows up
- electron-quick-start: 5-10 secs

I was just wondering where the performance issue is, portable? electron-builder?

I found an [issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/2548) in electron-builder that seems to indicate, that portable apps are extracted into a temp folder on app start, thats whats slow

Comment: Yes the electron-builder portable exe extracts the unpacked version. In my case in the folder C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\1ZvscrlLfEK1BonnPLcq0FFUDpk. 
Visual Studio Code does not use a portable exe to start the application.
Did you found a way to speed up the start up time of the portable exe?

Comment: @Ado sadly not and I guess this is just the nature of electron portable apps. The issue only really bothers on slow machines, I simply suggest everyone to use installers instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close this question:

### Problem:

As indicated in the comments, the problem really is the portable mode of electron-builder. Portable Apps first unpack themselves into a temporary folder on your computer which can be a cpu intensive task because of compression.

Only after the app files have been unpacked, the main.js is actually loaded by node / electron.

### Solutions:

#### Use an installer

When using an installer, the unpacking is done during installation of course, and not every time the app is started.

#### Use a splashimage (untested)

Although it is nowhere mentioned in the electron-builder docs, the code seems to indicate that you can set a `splashImage` bmp option:

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/master/packages/app-builder-lib/src/targets/nsis/nsisOptions.ts

```
/**
 * The image to show while the portable executable is extracting. This image must be a bitmap (`.bmp`) image.
 */
readonly splashImage?: string | null
```

That would at least make it clear something is happening, instead of the user clicking the icon multiple times because the app doesn't open

Comment: It seems this option is only available for portible mode, so if you are not using portable mode then this option will not help you

Comment: @Franco well yes, the option of not using the portable mode is indeed only possible when using the portable mode? If you are referring to the splash image "solution" then I suggest creating a second browser window, like explained here for example https://medium.com/red-buffer/how-to-create-a-splash-screen-for-electron-app-602b4da406d

Comment: Yes that is the way to go. Create 2nd browser window that launches immediately when whenReady is called.